# Dynamically change text in dialog

Tags: android

I am using an `alert dialog` that contains a `seekbar` in it. I'd like the text to change so the user knows what is being selected by the `seekbar`. The `seekbar` updates a `textview` on the UI dynamically, which I do in the `onProgressChanged` method. I can't make the same change to `dialog.setMessage` from the seekbar's progress - do I have to make a custom view for it? I'm currently implementing it as so:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder popDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
final SeekBar seek = new SeekBar(this);

popDialog.setMessage("Current Number: ");
popDialog.setView(seek);
seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
numView.setText(String.valueOf(progress));

...
```

Comment: I think you want to progressbar same as whtsapp registration right?

Comment: I have never used or seen whatsapp so I don't know what you're talking about, but I am using a seekbar to SET values, not a progress bar to measure the waiting during a thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution is to create a custom dialog using a new activity:

Create an activity to take care of the functions, and set it up with its own xml file with the components, and place

```
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"
```

inside the `<activity>` tag of the manifest.

Of course, there are different theme options, the important thing is the `.Dialog` setting.